# If I DDoS through a VPN, will they be able to resolve the attack to me?

Tags: vpn

As the title says; if I DDoS through a VPN, will they be able to resolve the attack to me?

Say I've got a VPN running on a VPS, connected to it, so my IP has changed. If I DDoS a server, will they be able to resolve the attack to me? Will they know I did it?

Note: I will not use this for bad purposes.

Comment: DDoS from a single connection?

Comment: What do you mean by "Will they know I did it?" What does that mean to you? Trace the IP? Ownership of the VPS? What scope are you talking about?

Comment: @schroeder: both.

Comment: We cannot possibly take on that entire scope. Please narrow down your question. We would have to know everything about your VPN, VPS, registration, networks, the type of attacks, etc.

Comment: How do you do a Distributed DOS through one single connection, expecting to use it as C&C on a bunch of bots. A single VPN connection is a soda straw otherwise and you're just embarrassing yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**The VPS**

Assuming it's your VPS that you pay for at a VPS provider, they could possibly trace you back. You're paying this by either a credit card or a PayPal like payment system.

Even if you do not use one of the payment options described above, if you purchased the VPS from your regular IP, the VPS provider will have this logged.

**The VPN**

Having a VPN connection does not always mean you're protected from "malicious" action. One example is DNS leakage where an improper configured VPN connection could still leak requests to your (home) ISP its DNS server.

Running a mail client, chat client or any other client in the background while having the VPN connection could possibly disclose it is you (assuming you connect to these services from your home IP as well.

It takes quite the discipline to prevent issues like this. Even browser finger printing could give you away.

**The DDoS**

You are talking about a DDoS, I assume for a moment that you only will use the VPN's IP to control the botnet.

In case the Command and Control Center is compromised by federal agencies it could possibly be traced back to you (see the VPN)

If this a serious and legal question, please supply more details as my answers are somewhat based on assumptions. And as we all know, assumption are the mother of all fuckups.